# PHP Regex for different languages

Tags: php, regex

I want to use regex as follows:

```
[a-z' ]*[a-z]
```

This won't work with different languages such as Chinese. Is it possible to create an inverse version of this regex to do the following:

Capture a word or words that are connected by a space

```
"Hey, july 2010"
=> hey
=> july

"hey what's up"
=> hey what's up

"汉漢字, 汉漢字 3004303"
=> 汉漢字
=> 汉漢字
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using php sorry

Comment: Maybe you could use a Unicode category, as [explained here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html). "PCRE and PHP do not support Unicode blocks, even though they support Unicode scripts."

Comment: Check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/dA4bD3/2).

Comment: The words  `Hey, july` aren't divided by a space, but a comma and a space. Can you make clear what you need ?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to do a Preg_Split to capture single words or multiple words that have only a space in between. So split would happen with comma space, or comma, or full number and space. "July 12, 2015" => "July" and "July 2010" => "July" and "black,blue , red"=>"back","blue","red"

Comment: @stribizhev , how can I capture "hey what's up" all together? So if it is only a space in between words, those words are captured together

Comment: **"I am trying to do a Preg_Split to capture single words or multiple words that have only a space in between. So split would happen with comma space, or comma, or full number and space"**  it doesn't  make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define your set of word characters: `[\pL'-]` (`\pL` [unicode letter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), single quote and hyphen).

Within word boundaries `\b[\pL'-]+\b` matches one word. Followed by any amount of words, that are preceded by one or more `\h+` horizonal spaces, the final pattern for use with preg_match_all:

```
/\b[\pL'-]+(?:\h+[\pL'-]+)*\b/u
```

Already put into pattern delimiters and set u-modifier for unicode functionality.

[Demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tW6lY7/1)

Comment: This is what I needed! This clarifies things but is still confusing. Thanks for your help